# Calculate content height of UITableview with dynamic rowHeight

Tags: ios

Somehow I got myself into a situation where I need to calculate total height of table in viewDidLoad of my ViewController.

I have a viewController with a scrollView, in that scrollView I have two container views which contain TableViewController subclasses, now I have scrolling turned off for those tableViews as there are not going to be many cells in those tables. And I have some other views of fixed size above between and below these two container views, all of these are stacked inside a vertical stack view. For sizing this stack view and the scrollView it's in I need sizes of the container views as all other sizes are fixed.

So I want to calculate what is the total height going to be for the tables inside the container view. Is there a way I can calculate their size? I'm using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0):

This is tough to do because you would need to do it once all the cells for the table view have been created so the table view has to be big enough initially.  And then there is the issue of knowing when all that is done.  Do you need to use UITableViewControllers?  In this type of case I would convert the UITableViewCell xibs to normal view xibs or write them in code and add them to a container view programmatically. Then you can force the layout so you can get the height. Or even better, you probably don't need the height in this case, you just let auto layout do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
     tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```